# App widget not displaying on Oreo

Tags: android, android-widget

Instead, the widget area displays an error message saying "Problem while loading widget"

In the log, I see these errors when adding the app widget :

```
07-24 15:57:24.651 2057-5433/? E/RemoteViews: Package name com.theapp not found

07-24 15:57:24.651 2057-2057/? W/AppWidgetHostView: updateAppWidget couldn't find any view, using error view
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0b0034 type #0x5 is not valid
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2139)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1143)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:421)
        at android.widget.RemoteViews.inflateView(RemoteViews.java:3498)
        at android.widget.RemoteViews.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.widget.RemoteViews$AsyncApplyTask.doInBackground(RemoteViews.java:3600)
        at android.widget.RemoteViews$AsyncApplyTask.doInBackground(RemoteViews.java:3596)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

The widget displays fine on Android versions pre 8

EDIT: Here is my widget layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/appwidget_background"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/button_settings"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/app_name" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/button_on"
            android:layout_width="56dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/on" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/button_off"
            android:layout_width="56dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/off" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

and meta data file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="40dp"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="0"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/widget_preview"
    android:configure="com.theapp.appwidget.AppWidgetActivity"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/appwidget"
    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical" />
```

Comment: Hmm, the stack trace says it's trying to load an `R.dimen` as an `R.layout`. I can't really think of how that could happen, if it's working on prior versions.

Comment: How can you tell it's trying to load an R.dimen ? What is type #0x5 ?

Comment: An `R.dimen`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html#TYPE_DIMENSION. What is `0x7f0b0034` assigned to in your `R.java`? If you've rebuilt since that stack trace above, that might've changed, so check do a fresh run before you go digging.

Comment: 0x7f0b0034 is the id of the appwidget.xml file. I've cleaned and rebuilt project but still see the error. Could it be related to the firt error message: E/RemoteViews: Package name com.theapp not found

Comment: Possibly. Is that your app's package name? I assumed you'd just grabbed an extra, irrelevant line from the log.

Comment: No it's not the app package name. But it is the correct app package name in the actual log.

Comment: It seems to be failing to create the resource `Context` for your app, so it falls back to its own `Context`, which is why that hex value corresponds to a completely different resource type. It's apparently an `R.dimen` in its own package. That first line is logged when a `NameNotFoundException` is thrown. Is this happening on just one particular device? Or have you tested on multiple Oreo devices/emulators?

Comment: I've tested on an S8 device running OREO and it works fine. I've the same problem on an other PIXEL device though. It seems the problem occurs only on PIXEL devices... very strange

Comment: Yeah, I found another question with the exact same issue, but it's been deleted, so you can't see it. (Leaving a link here for my future reference: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51272322) They say it's failing on a Pixel 2 with Android 8.1, but it works just fine on 9.0. I'm not sure that there's anything you can do about it, other than maybe upgrading, if you are running 8.1 and you can upgrade.

Comment: Of course, this would only really be helpful for your personal devices, I suppose. Won't help your users with the issue, unless they can upgrade to, and are willing to.

Comment: Thanks a lot for finding this. The link opens a Page Not Found though

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant by "you can't see it". :-) I have 10k+ rep, so I can see deleted posts. The question is basically just a stack trace like yours, their layout, and the OP saying they're only having the issue on Pixel 2 devices. The info I mentioned above was in the comments. Here's a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j998l.png.

Comment: I wonder why has this post been removed then

Comment: The OP deleted it themself about two days after they posted it. I don't know if that means they found a solution, or they gave up, or maybe they just didn't care anymore.

Answer (score 1):

"Problem while loading widget" + your limited stacktrace indicate a layout problem. It would help if you showed your layout file. Go back and check all your attributes, images and views. There may be an element to your layout that isn't allowed for an appwidget as they are restricted in what views can be used. Also check that you sized your widget properly in the metadata xml file, and check that your padding follows the guidelines. The android guideline describes how you should size it and use padding: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design

Comment: I've updated my layout file and metadata xml file so they follow dimension restrictions, but I still see the error message in the widget

Comment: I did a test with your layout (without the custom drawable since I didn't have that) and it worked for me. What is your custom background drawable? If its a vector drawable, that's your problem, appwidgets won't support those.  A shape drawable should be fine. By the way, device tested was v8 Oreo

Comment: I also notice that you don't have dynamic padding set for your margin.  Per the guidelines you should create two dimens.xml files, one for your values folder, and the other for values-v14, with the v14 dimen set to 0dp and the other set to 8dp. See this page for more detail: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/#CreatingLayout

Comment: Thanks @RebeccaMcBath, I've checked the background drawable and added dimens.xml files, but the same problem is still here...